# inverse of 'indent-tabs-mode'

Tags: indentation

According to `indent-tabs-mode`,

> Indentation can insert tabs if this is non-nil.

`nil` means indentation cannot use tabs. I need the opposite of this option, prevent indentation from using spaces as tabs.

I need this to match a formatting convention (eclipse) where tabs are mandatory.

What is the simplest way to achieve this? I'm using plain `java-mode`, whose tab is bound to `(c-indent-line-or-region &optional ARG REGION)`, which seems to use `(symbol-function 'indent-according-to-mode)`, which eventually uses `c-shift-line-indentation`, but I don't see any options to configure using tabs only. Am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Ultimately* it's up to the individual mode to decide how it indents things, but `indent-tabs-mode` is *generally* respected, and all you need do is set it to a non-nil value.

The canonical non-nil value is `t` when no other value is more appropriate.

`indent-tabs-mode` is automatically buffer-local, and you can use the mode hook for `java-mode` to set it in any buffer using that mode.

```el
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook 'my-java-mode-hook)

(defun my-java-mode-hook ()
  "Custom behaviours for `java-mode-hook'."
  (setq indent-tabs-mode t))
```

Provided java-mode only ever indents to multiples of `tab-width`, this ought to give you tab-only indentation.

If not, you would need to determine how to control the level of indentation in java-mode so that you can set that (and/or tab-width -- another buffer-local value) to coincide, so that only tabs will be required.

Naturally if there are circumstances when java-mode needs to indent to a column which is *not* an exact tab-width multiple, it won't be possible for it to use only tabs.

Comment: in this case, java-mode just resorts to c-indent-line-or-region. although your answer is helpful in giving some insight into how indentation works, I'd like to accept my own answer since it fixes my problem and has a little bit more "research" (basically, `(setq indent-tabs-mode t)` alone did not work for me)

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: `(setf tab-width 4)`

I was seeing the unwanted behavior of 4 spaces being inserted despite `indent-tabs-mode` being `t`. Thankfully, emacs is free software, so I was able to follow my `TAB` key press all the way down to the C source:

```
`TAB->c-indent-line-or-region->(symbol-function 'indent-according-to-mode)->c-shift-line-indentation->indent-to`
```

indent-to is defined in C source. the relevant portion is:

```
if (indent_tabs_mode)
{
  Lisp_Object n;
  XSETFASTINT (n, mincol / tab_width - fromcol / tab_width);
  if (XFASTINT (n) != 0)
{
  Finsert_char (make_number ('\t'), n, Qt);

  fromcol = (mincol / tab_width) * tab_width;
}
}
```

clearly n was being 0. This is because `mincol / tab_width` was `4 / 8`, because tab-width was too big. Setting `(setf tab-width 4)` allows the function to indent using a tab, and no spaces are needed.

Finally:

`(add-hook 'java-mode-hook (lambda () (setf tab-width 4)))`